# There are at least 4 global sections on a complete intersection curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Vakil 19.8 C, self-study.

We take a regular complete intersection of a quadric $Q$ and a cubic $K$ in $\mathbb P^3_k$, producing a genus $4$ curve $C$. The problem asks us to show that there are at least 4 sections of $\mathcal O_C(1)$, i.e.

$$h^0(C, \mathcal O_C(1)) \geq 4$$

and says that this translates to showing that $C$ does not lie in a hyperplane. I do not see why either of these statements is true.

First, showing $C$ is not in a hyperplane is trivial it seems. If it were in a degree $d$ hypersurface, the hypersurface would have to look like $f_1Q + f_2K$, where $f_i$ are homogeneous polynomials of the correct degree. This is impossible if $d = 1$.

Second, if I ignore the translated problem and focus on the original problem, the only thing I can think to use is Riemann-Roch and Serre Duality in combination:

$$h^0(\mathcal O_C(1)) = \deg \mathcal O_C(1) - g + 1 + h^1(\mathcal O_C(1)) = 1 - 4 + 1 + h^0(\omega_C \otimes \mathcal O_C(-1))$$

but I do not see how to show that last term is $\geq 6$. We know $h^0(\omega_C) = 4$, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $C$ is a complete intersection, $\deg C = 2\cdot 3 = 6$, which means that actually $\deg \mathcal O_C(1) = 6$ (i.e. $C$ intersects a general hyperplane in $6$ points) giving us $h^0(\mathcal O_C(1)) = 6 - 4 + 1 + h^0(\omega_C \otimes \mathcal O_C(-1))$.

To determine this last term (which needs to be $\geq 1$), note that $\deg \omega_C = 6$ so the tensor product is a line bundle of degree $0$, hence has a section if and only if it is isomorphic to $\mathcal O_C$ which is itself the case if and only if $\mathcal O_C(1) \cong \omega_C$. This follows from iterated adjunction:
$$
\omega_Q \cong \omega_{\mathbb P^3}\otimes \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(Q)|_Q \cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(-4)\otimes\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(2)|_Q \cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(-2)|_Q,
$$

and then
$$
\omega_C \cong \omega_Q\otimes (\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(K)|_Q)|_C \cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(-2)|_Q \otimes (\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(3)|_Q)|_C \cong \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(1)|_C = \mathcal O_C(1),
$$

where I've maybe gone a bit overboard with the restriction notation, but hopefully the idea is clear: everything happening is with line bundles that have been restricted from projective space.

Comment: I jive well with this answer up until you show $\omega_C \simeq \mathcal O_C(1)$. We have not covered this adjunction formula in Vakil up until this point. For example, I do not see where your first isomorphism involving $\omega_Q$ comes from.

Comment: Ooh, this may be a bit trickier then. What tools do you know at present for working with the canonical class?

Comment: All we know is that $\omega_C$ has degree $2g - 2$, has $g$ sections. We also know Serre Duality and Riemann-Roch, and that $\omega_C$ for $\mathbb P^n$ is just $\mathcal O(-n - 1)$. See section 19.2 of Vakil's FOAG to see the set of tools we have in general (it's too large to include here, but not too long to quickly browse).

Comment: I just read Ravi's exact statement, and I think you are supposed to solve the translated problem, which you have done. The equivalence is something like: if $C$ lies in a plane, then $\mathcal O_C(1)$ has one fewer section than the expected $4$ coming from the monomials on $\mathbb P^3$ because the equation of the plane restricts to the zero section.

Comment: I just scribbled some details on scrap paper and I think you just need to use the long exact cohomology sequences associated to (1) the sequence $0 \to I_C \to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3} \to \mathcal O_C \to 0$ twisted by $1$, and (2) the Koszul resolution of $I_C$. Are you familiar with these?

Comment: I know the first one. I've never heard of a Koszul resolution, but I think may know what you mean. Would you mind clarifying?

Comment: The Koszul resolution is the standard resolution of the ideal of the zero locus of a vector bundle using exterior powers of that bundle's dual. In this case it should look like $0 \to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(-5) \to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(-2) \oplus \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^3}(-3) \to I_C \to 0$. The map to the ideal is given as a matrix by $(Q \,\,\,\, K)$ while the other interesting map is given by $\left(\matrix{-K \\ Q}\right)$, where I am denoting the equations of the quadric and cubic by $Q=0$ and $K=0$ as well.